# adaptive main column width around sidebar

Tags: css

I'm working on a custom stylesheet, therefore I have no way of editing the HTML itself. The idea is quite simple. I need to make the main column or its contents to dynamically arrange itself under the sidebar whenever the end of the latter is reached. Frankly I'm ready to give up on this because I don't think it's possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#content {
      width: 500px;
      height: 450px;
      display: block;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      position: relative;
}
.thin {

      width: 100%;
}
.name {
      display: block;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.sidebar {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      margin-top:5px;
      width: 100px;
}
.box.a1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.box.a2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.box.a3 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.main_background {
      float: left;
}
.main {
      float: left;
      width: 375px;
}
.box.b1 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box.b2 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box.b3 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box.b4 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Noplacetorun/1z4etcxa/7/) representing the current situation.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Noplacetorun/sfpLzmrj/) representing the desired outcome.

Comment: On your first jsfiddle, are those your actual classes affiliated with your HTML?

Comment: Just noticed that I forgot to edit a part of the css out. For example purposes, the names are different but the structure is the same.

Comment: Is it all the same large div that extends from the top to below the sidebar, or is it broken up into multiple `div`s like your jsfiddle displays?

Comment: It is exactly like jsfiddle. The sidebar `div` contains `div`s, and the main column `div` contains another `div` which respectively contains the `div`s in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it with **CSS only**, you could use a `::before` pseudo element inside your main-div and float it to the right (`.main::before` in my example below).

That way it would act as a "placeholder" for your sidebar. You would need to `position: absolute` the sidebar to the right and place it directly above the placeholder-pseudo-element. Don't forget to give the `box.b` classes `overflow: hidden;`.

This solution only works if you know the size of the sidebar though. Other solutions would include JavaScript.

Here is my example (I colored the placeholder purple):

```css
#content {
      width: 500px;
      height: 450px;
      display: block;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      position: relative;
}
.thin {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
}
.name {
      display: block;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      width: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
}
.box.a1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.box.a2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.box.a3 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      display: block;
      margin-top:5px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.main_background {
      width: 100%;
}
.main {
}
.main::before {
  background-color: rgba(89, 39, 140, 0.4);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 165px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box.b1 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box.b2 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box.b3 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box.b4 {
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="thin">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="box a1"></div>
        <div class="box a2"></div>
        <div class="box a3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_background">
        <div class="main">
       <div class="box b1"></div>
       <div class="box b2"></div>
       <div class="box b3"></div>
       <div class="box b4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the height of the sidebar may vary. I guess I'll have to determine the highest possible value and go with that. JavaScript is not an option, so I'll mark your answer as a solution. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.